# Python Flask TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' for an election voting app

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Python Flask to create an election voting app. I created a section for admin where one of the functionalities is to register candidates. However, I am getting the above error when I try the candidate register functionality. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my code and Stack Trace:

```py
views.py

from app import app
from .models import VotesModel,CandidateModel, UserModel,db
from flask import redirect, render_template, flash,url_for,request
from flask_login import login_required, current_user,logout_user
from flask_cors import cross_origin
import string
import json
import random 

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/profile")
@login_required
def profile():
    prez = CandidateModel.query.filter_by(post="President").all()
    vice = CandidateModel.query.filter_by(post="Vice-President").all()
    voter = VotesModel.query.filter_by(roll_num=current_user.roll_num).first()
    return render_template("profile.html",name=current_user.name,prez=prez,vice=vice,voter=voter)

@app.route("/profile", methods=["POST"])
def post_vote():
    president = request.form.get('president')
    vicepresident = request.form.get('vice-president')

    voted = VotesModel.query.filter_by(roll_num=current_user.roll_num).first()
    if not voted:
        voter = VotesModel(roll_num=current_user.roll_num,voter_id=current_user.id,post_1=int(president),post_2=int(vicepresident))
        db.session.add(voter)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))
    

@app.route("/candidate")
def candidate():
    prez = CandidateModel.query.filter_by(post="President").all()
    vice = CandidateModel.query.filter_by(post="Vice-President").all()
    return render_template("candidate.html",prez=prez,vice=vice)

@app.route("/candidate_register")
@login_required
def candidate_register():
    if current_user.admin !=1:
        logout_user()
        flash('You do not have required authorization')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    else:
        return render_template("candidate_register.html")

@app.route("/candidate_register", methods=["POST"])
def candidate_post():
    roll_num = request.form.get('roll_num')
    first_name = request.form.get('first_name')
    last_name = request.form.get('last_name')
    batch = request.form.get('batch')
    course = request.form.get('course')
    department = request.form.get('department')
    post = request.form.get('post')
    pic_path = request.form.get('pic_path')
    agenda = request.form.get('agenda')
    
    roll_no = UserModel.query.filter_by(roll_num =roll_num).first()
    cand = CandidateModel.query.filter_by(roll_num = roll_num).first()

    error = False

    if not 10000000 <= int(roll_no) < 99999999:
        flash('Roll Number is not valid. Should be 8 digits.','error')
        error = True

    if cand:
        flash('Candidate has already been registered.','error')
        return redirect(url_for('candidate_register'))
    
    if not set(first_name).issubset(string.ascii_letters + " "):
        flash('Name can only contain alphabets.','error')
        error = True
    
    if not set(last_name).issubset(string.ascii_letters + " "):
        flash('Name can only contain alphabets.','error')
        error = True

    if not first_name and not last_name:
        flash('Name cannot be left blank.','error')
        error = True

    if not batch and not course and not department:
        flash('Please fill in all the details. Batch, Course and Department information is neccessary.','error')
        error = True
    
    if error:
        return redirect(url_for('candidate_register'))
    else:
        candidate = CandidateModel(roll_num=roll_num, first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,batch=batch,course=course,department=department,post=post,pic_path=pic_path,agenda=agenda)
        db.session.add(candidate)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Candidate successfully registered.','success')
        return redirect(url_for('candidate_register'))

@app.route("/live_result")
def live_result():
    prez = CandidateModel.query.filter_by(post="President").all()
    vice = CandidateModel.query.filter_by(post="Vice-President").all()
    labels=[]
    data=[]
    labels1=[]
    data1=[]
    for candidate in prez:
        name = candidate.first_name+" "+candidate.last_name
        labels.append(name)
        vote=VotesModel.query.filter(VotesModel.post_1==candidate.roll_num).count()
        data.append(vote)
    for candidate in vice:
        name = candidate.first_name+" "+candidate.last_name
        labels1.append(name)
        vote=VotesModel.query.filter(VotesModel.post_2==candidate.roll_num).count()
        data1.append(vote)
 
    return render_template('graph.html',labels=labels,data=data,labels1=labels1,data1=data1)


@app.route("/vote/count")
@cross_origin()
def voteCount():
    prez = CandidateModel.query.filter_by(post="President").all()
    vice = CandidateModel.query.filter_by(post="Vice-President").all()
    labels=[]
    data=[]
    labels1=[]
    data1=[]
    for candidate in prez:
        name = candidate.first_name+" "+candidate.last_name
        labels.append(name)
        vote=VotesModel.query.filter(VotesModel.post_1==candidate.roll_num).count()
        data.append(vote)
    for candidate in vice:
        name = candidate.first_name+" "+candidate.last_name
        labels1.append(name)
        vote=VotesModel.query.filter(VotesModel.post_2==candidate.roll_num).count()
        data1.append(vote)

    output = {"data": data,
            "labels": labels,
            "data1": data1,
            "labels1": labels1}
    response = app.response_class(
        response=json.dumps(output),
        status=200,
        mimetype='application/json'
    )
    return response
```

This is my schema named models.py

models.py

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
# from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash,check_password_hash
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import ForeignKey
from flask_login import UserMixin

db = SQLAlchemy() 

class UserModel(UserMixin,db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    roll_num = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80),nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    admin =  db.Column(db.Integer,default=0)
    votes = db.relationship('VotesModel', backref='voter', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.name}', '{self.roll_num}')"

class VotesModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'votes'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    roll_num = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, unique=True)
    voter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    post_1 = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False )
    post_2 = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Voter('{self.roll_num}')"

class CandidateModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'candidates'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    roll_num = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, unique=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    batch = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    course = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    department = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    post = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    pic_path = db.Column(db.String(120), default='images/default.png')
    agenda =  db.Column(db.String(300), default="No agenda")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Candidate('{self.first_name}','{self.batch}','{self.course}','{self.department}')"
```

I have also attached the templates  candidate_register.html and profile.html

candidate_register

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="column is-8 is-offset-2">
    <h3 class="title">Register a new candidate</h3>
    <div class="box">
        {% with errors = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["error"]) %}
        {% if errors %}
            <div class="notification is-danger">
            <ul>
                {%- for msg in errors %}
                    <li>{{ msg }}</li>
                {% endfor -%}
            </ul>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        {% with success = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["success"]) %}
        {% if success %}
            <div class="notification is-success">
            {%- for msg in success %}
                <ul>{{ msg }}. Go to <a href="{{ url_for('candidate') }}">Candidate Info</a> to view details.</ul>
            {% endfor -%}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        <form method="POST" action="/candidate_register">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input is-small" type="integer" name="roll_num" placeholder="Roll Number" autofocus="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input is-small" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" autofocus="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input is-small" type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" autofocus="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                  <textarea class="textarea is-small"  name="agenda" placeholder="Candidate Agenda" autofocus=""></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input is-small" type="text" name="batch" placeholder="Batch" autofocus="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input is-small" type="text" name="course" placeholder="Course" autofocus="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input is-small" type="text" name="department" placeholder="Department" autofocus="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <div class="select is-rounded is-small">
                        <select name="post">
                          <option value="President">President</option>
                          <option value="Vice-President">Vice-President</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input is-small" type="text" name="pic_path" placeholder="Add path to candidate's picture eg. /static/images/img.jpg" autofocus="">
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="button is-block is-info is-small is-fullwidth">Register Candidate</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

profile.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1 class="title">
  Welcome, {{ name }}!
</h1>
{% if voter%}
  <h1 class="subtitle has-text-success"> Your vote has been cast.</h1>
  
{%else%}
  <h2 class="subtitle">
      You can cast your vote here.<br>
  </h2>
  <div class="columns">
      <div class="column is-4">
        <img src="static/images/3.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="column is-4 ">
        
        <div class="box">
        <h3 class="title has-text-dark">Voting Form</h3>

        Do take a look at the <a href="{{ url_for('candidate') }}"><u>candidates</u> </a> standing in the election before casting your vote.
        <br> <br>

        <form method="POST" action="/profile">
          <div class="field ">
            <label class="label">President</label>
            <div class="select" >
              <select name="president">
                {% for prez in prez %}
                    <option value ={{prez.roll_num}}>{{prez.first_name}} {{prez.last_name}} ({{prez.roll_num}})</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </div>
            
          </div> 
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Vice-President</label>
              <div class="select" >
              <select name="vice-president">
                {% for vice in vice %}
                    <option value ={{vice.roll_num}}>{{vice.first_name}} {{vice.last_name}} ({{vice.roll_num}})</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
              </div>
              <br>
              <br>

            <div class="field">
              <button class="button  is-success">Cast Vote</button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-4">
      <img src="static/images/4.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is my stack trace

```
    File "/home/dg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2091, in __call__

    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    File "/home/dg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app

    response = self.handle_exception(e)

    File "/home/dg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function

    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))

    File "/home/dg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app

    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

    File "/home/dg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

    File "/home/dg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function

    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))

    File "/home/dg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.dispatch_request()

    File "/home/dg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request

    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)

    File "/home/dg/Projects/Voting2/Flask-Voting-App/app/views.py", line 70, in candidate_post

    if not 10000000 <= int(roll_no) < 99999999:

    TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Presumably it's possible for `roll_no` to be `None` so you would want to check for that when you're checking that `roll_no` is a valid number.

Comment: That’s interesting, how would you do that?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It appears your issue starts here:

```
roll_no = UserModel.query.filter_by(roll_num =roll_num).first()
```

Most likely that means that your database query is resulting in a null or missing value being returned, which is expressed as `None`.

When you try to convert and compare that value here:

```
if not 10000000 <= int(roll_no) < 99999999:
        flash('Roll Number is not valid. Should be 8 digits.','error')
        error = True
```

`roll_no` is `None`, so it cannot be converted to an `int`, and generates as error, as exhibited here:

```
>>> int(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

One remedy would be to try to figure out why you don't have usable values in your data, and address that.

Otherwise, you could simply consider the missing value an invalid number, like this:

```
if not roll_no or not 10000000 <= int(roll_no) < 99999999:
        flash('Roll Number is not valid. Should be 8 digits.','error')
        error = True
```

The `not roll_no` would also be true if `roll_no` is `0` (assuming that's a possible value), so you could also be more explicit about what you're checking with:

```
if roll_no is None or not 10000000 <= int(roll_no) < 99999999:
```

Comment: Thank you, your method seemed to have resolved the None type error. However, I am getting a new                                                                                                                   
 **Type Error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'UserModel' ** .  Any idea how I can resolve that too? The new error comes from the same line as before

Comment: @MaxwellAgyemang: Sorry, I don't know enough about Flask model types to help with that. See my first point, you'll need to understand your data and how it's used.